# Razor- Giving an 'attribute' to a radioButtonFor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, razor

I have radio buttons that are defined like this

```
 @foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
 {
    <td>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Parts[i].SelectedActionType, actionType, new { name = "partRadio" })
    </td>
 }
```

Where I try setting the 'name as "partRadio", (I tried doing  `@name` and `Name` but neither option worked.

In my JQuery code I have it where a row is cloned after a checkbox is clicked,
that code looks like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tr_clone input.part-class').change(function () {

                let Id = $(this).attr('id');
                let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');

                if ($(Id).is(":checked")) {
                    // remove cloned row

                    $("#AllTxt").hide();
                    $("#editQty").show();
                }
                else {
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
                    var $clone = $tr.clone();
                    $clone.find('td');
                    $tr.after($clone);
                    $($clone).find(".part-class").hide();
                    $clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", function (el) { return el.name + 'clone' });
                    $("#AllTxt").show();
                    $("#editQty").hide();               
                }

            });
        });
```

Where it should just be appending 'clone' to 'partRadio' but instead the HTML is rendering the name as
'name = undefinedclone`

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the first argument of the `attr()` handler function is the index of the element, not a reference to the element itself.

To fix this you need to accept the element correctly using the *second* argument provided to the function which is the current value of the `name` attribute:

```
$clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", function (i, n) { 
   return n + 'clone' 
});
```

Note that this can be shortened using an arrow function:

```
$clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", (i, n) => n + 'clone');
```